# how to group nested obects using underscorejs and get the matching data length

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

How to group the matching data in array of object and get the matching data length to get the average value.

```js
var getdataObj = [{
  "finalUrl": "https://www.amazon.in/",
  "fetchTime": "2022-10-15T08:58:18.485Z",
  "audits": {   
    "first-contentful-paint": {
      "displayValue": "1.2"
    },
    }
},
{
  "finalUrl": "https://www.google.in/",
  "fetchTime": "2022-11-15T08:58:18.485Z",
  "audits": {   
    "first-contentful-paint": {
      "displayValue": "6.2"
    },
    }
},
{
  "finalUrl": "https://www.flipkart.in/",
  "fetchTime": "2022-10-15T08:58:18.485Z",
  "audits": {   
    "first-contentful-paint": {
      "displayValue": "4.2"
    },
    }
},
{
  "finalUrl": "https://www.amazon.in/",
  "fetchTime": "2022-10-15T08:58:18.485Z",
  "audits": {   
    "first-contentful-paint": {
      "displayValue": "3.7"
    },
    }
},
{
  "finalUrl": "https://www.google.in/",
  "fetchTime": "2022-12-15T08:58:18.485Z",
  "audits": {   
    "first-contentful-paint": {
      "displayValue": "3.2"
    },
    }
}]
```

This is the array of object I am getting. How to group the matching elements here.

- Need to group the matching URL.
- Seperate the value based on month and Year.

**Expected Result :**

https://www.amazon.in/
month : 2022-10
TotalValue : 4.9  //(1.2+3.7)

My Code Logic :

```js
var groupedData = _.chain(getdataObj)
          .groupBy('fetchTime')
          .map(function (group, datekey) {
          return {
              Month: datekey.substr(0,7),
                WTs: _.chain(group)
                  .groupBy("finalUrl")
                  .map(function (group, key) {
                  return {
                      WT: key,
                     TotalWeight: _.reduce(group, function(acc, i){ 
                          acc.speed += parseFloat(i['audits']['first-contentful-paint']['displayValue']);                         
                          return acc; 
                      }, {speed : 0})
                  };
              })
              .value()
          }})
          .value();
```

And i need to get the length. Ex : I have three datas in October month. So my Avarage calculation should be,

https://www.amazon.in/
month : 2022-10

https://www.flipkart.in/
month : 2022-10

TotalValue : 9.1 / 3 => 3.03

Can anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Sample fiddle i added here : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tf2ujb5/)

```js
var data = [{
    fetchTime: '2022-12-15T08:58:18.485Z',
    finalUrl: 'https://www.amazon.in/',
    audits: {
        "first-contentful-paint": {
        "displayValue": "3.4"
    },
    "largest-contentful-paint": {
      "displayValue": "2.3"
    },
    }
}, {
    fetchTime: '2022-12-15T08:58:18.485Z',
    finalUrl: 'https://www.google.in/',
    audits: {
    "first-contentful-paint": {
        "displayValue": "1.2"
    },
    "largest-contentful-paint": {
      "displayValue": "3.4"
    },
    }
}, {
    fetchTime: '2023-02-15T08:58:18.485Z',
    finalUrl: 'https://www.amazon.in/',
    audits: {
    "first-contentful-paint": {
        "displayValue": "6.2"
    },
    "largest-contentful-paint": {
      "displayValue": "3.5"
    },
    }
}, {
    fetchTime: '2022-11-15T08:58:18.485Z',
    finalUrl: 'https://www.flipkart.in/',
    audits: {
    "first-contentful-paint": {
        "displayValue": "4.2"
    },
    "largest-contentful-paint": {
      "displayValue": "5.3"
    },
    }
}, {
    fetchTime: '2023-01-15T08:58:18.485Z',
    finalUrl: 'https://www.google.in/',
    audits: {
    "first-contentful-paint": {
        "displayValue": "7.2"
    },
    "largest-contentful-paint": {
      "displayValue": "8.3"
    },
    }
}];

var groupedData = _.chain(data)
    .groupBy('fetchTime')
    .map(function (group, key) {
    return {
        Month: key,
        WTs: _.chain(group)
            .groupBy("finalUrl")
            .map(function (group, key) {
            return {
                WT: key,
                TotalWeight: _.reduce(group, function(acc, i){ 
                    acc.speed += parseFloat(i['audits']['first-contentful-paint']['displayValue']);
                    acc.large += parseFloat(i['audits']['largest-contentful-paint']['displayValue']);
                }, {speed:0, large:0})
            };
        })
        .value()
    }})
    .value();


console.log(groupedData);

_.each(groupedData, function(m) {
    console.log("Month: ", m.Month);
    _.each(m.WTs, function(wt) {
        console.log("  ", wt.WT,  ": ", wt.TotalWeight);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. The function that you pass to `reduce`, also known as the iteratee, must *return the new value of the accumulator*. In order to also collect the length, simply add it to the object returned from the `map` iteratee.

```js
var data = [{
    fetchTime: '2022-12-15T08:58:18.485Z',
    finalUrl: 'https://www.amazon.in/',
    audits: {
        "first-contentful-paint": {
            "displayValue": "3.4"
        },
        "largest-contentful-paint": {
            "displayValue": "2.3"
        },
    }
}, {
    fetchTime: '2022-12-15T08:58:18.485Z',
    finalUrl: 'https://www.google.in/',
    audits: {
        "first-contentful-paint": {
            "displayValue": "1.2"
        },
        "largest-contentful-paint": {
          "displayValue": "3.4"
        },
    }
}, {
    fetchTime: '2023-02-15T08:58:18.485Z',
    finalUrl: 'https://www.amazon.in/',
    audits: {
        "first-contentful-paint": {
            "displayValue": "6.2"
        },
        "largest-contentful-paint": {
          "displayValue": "3.5"
        },
    }
}, {
    fetchTime: '2022-11-15T08:58:18.485Z',
    finalUrl: 'https://www.flipkart.in/',
    audits: {
        "first-contentful-paint": {
            "displayValue": "4.2"
        },
        "largest-contentful-paint": {
          "displayValue": "5.3"
        },
    }
}, {
    fetchTime: '2023-01-15T08:58:18.485Z',
    finalUrl: 'https://www.google.in/',
    audits: {
        "first-contentful-paint": {
            "displayValue": "7.2"
        },
        "largest-contentful-paint": {
          "displayValue": "8.3"
        },
    }
}];

function yearMonth(dateString) {
    return dateString.slice(0, 7);
}

var groupedData = _.chain(data)
    .groupBy(_.compose(yearMonth, _.property('fetchTime')))
    .map(function (group, key) {
        return {
            Month: key,
            WTs: _.chain(group)
                .groupBy("finalUrl")
                .map(function (group, key) {
                    return {
                        WT: key,
                        TotalWeight: _.reduce(group, function(acc, i){ 
                            acc.speed += parseFloat(i['audits']['first-contentful-paint']['displayValue']);
                            acc.large += parseFloat(i['audits']['largest-contentful-paint']['displayValue']);
                            return acc;
                        }, {speed:0, large:0}),
                        length: group.length
                    };
                })
                .value()
        };
    })
    .value();

_.each(groupedData, function(m) {
    console.log("Month: ", m.Month);
    _.each(m.WTs, function(wt) {
        console.log("  ", wt.WT,  ": ", wt.TotalWeight);
        console.log('Average speed: ', wt.TotalWeight.speed / wt.length);
        console.log('Average large: ', wt.TotalWeight.large / wt.length);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/underscore@1.13.6/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a combined key for grouping and add `displayValue` to `total`.

```js
const
    data = [{ finalUrl: "https://www.amazon.in/", fetchTime: "2022-10-15T08:58:18.485Z", audits: { "first-contentful-paint": { displayValue: "1.2" } } }, { finalUrl: "https://www.google.in/", fetchTime: "2022-11-15T08:58:18.485Z", audits: { "first-contentful-paint": { displayValue: "6.2" } } }, { finalUrl: "https://www.flipkart.in/", fetchTime: "2022-10-15T08:58:18.485Z", audits: { "first-contentful-paint": { displayValue: "4.2" } } }, { finalUrl: "https://www.amazon.in/", fetchTime: "2022-10-15T08:58:18.485Z", audits: { "first-contentful-paint": { displayValue: "3.7" } } }, { finalUrl: "https://www.google.in/", fetchTime: "2022-12-15T08:58:18.485Z", audits: { "first-contentful-paint": { displayValue: "3.2" } } }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { finalUrl, fetchTime, audits: { ["first-contentful-paint"]: { displayValue } } }) => {
        const
            month = fetchTime.slice(0, 7),
            key = [finalUrl, month].join('|');
            
        r[key] ??= { finalUrl, month, total: 0 };
        r[key].total += +displayValue;
        
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```